Estimation in generalized additive models
I'm currently trying to learn about generalized additive models (GAMs) with the book Generalized Additive Models An Introduction with R by Simon N. Wood. However, I have some questions regarding the following part.
In Chapter 6.1 it is stated that the GAM becomes an over-parameterized GLM of the form
$$g(\mu_i) = X_i\beta, \quad y_i \sim EF(\mu_i, \phi),$$
where $EF$ stands for exponential family, and that $\beta$ is estimated by maximisation of
$$l_p(\beta) = l(\beta) - \frac{1}{2\phi}\sum_j\lambda_j\beta^TS_j\beta.$$
My questions are:

What is the justification for simply subtracting the sum of the penalty terms from the log-likelihood and then maximizing the resulting function with respect to $\beta$?
Where does the factor $\frac{1}{2\phi}$ come from?

Any help is much appreciated!
